# Metric on a punctured riemann surface

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, metric-tensor, conformal-field-theory, topology

In string theory, it is often said that the scattering amplitudes of $n$-particles are related to Riemann surface with $n$-punctures. How literal is this statement? And what does a metric on a Riemann surface with $n$-punctures look like?

Comment: How did you come across this "often said" statement without also coming across the actual technical meaning? Usually, this should be found in a string theory intro text right next to the very definition of the stringy amplitude as a sum over punctured worldsheets, and so reading any intro to string theory would answer this question.

Comment: I have removed some comments -- please remember to use comments for asking clarifications or suggesting improvements to the question. If there are clarifications, please edit them into the question and do not leave them down in the comments. Thanks!